# Word to describe a 'homemade' way to fix something.

Tags: single-word-requests

I am an artist and making some work, instead of buying some expensive equipment to monitor sound, im just wrapping a microphone in gaffa tape.

Is there a word to describe this kind of thing? Not homemade...not DIY...

Thanks! x

Answer (score 1):

A slightly negative term is **rigging** (progressive verb) or **rig** (noun). For example, `He rigged the door to stay shut`. There are various versions of "rig", such as "jerry-rigging", "jimmy-rigging", and "jury-rigging".

Another option is **MacGyver**: `It's broken? You could always MacGyver it.`

A more formal term might be **improvise**: `She used an improvised canvas.`

Comment: Improvised maybe. It also needs to be a positive thing.

Comment: not sure if avant-garde is correct?

Comment: Avant-garde is not bad, although it might be a little too extravagant for this particular case since it implies that there is a newfangled benefit being introduced. Invention or creation might work. If I were more artistic, I might recommend using a metaphor of some kind that portrays the most positive aspects of the contraption, perhaps based on appearance. Naturally the metaphor were better tailored to your particular audience.

Answer (score 1):

In Chemistry and Physics, some researchers used to boast of "**string and sealing-wax**" solutions.

The name stuck even when a device was made of polymer and Araldite.
It was still called "string and sealing wax" when a slow release timer for fish studies was made out of a peppermint (Polo) link. Bigger projects were "paper and string."

Can you update it?
"Bubble-wrap and Gaffer-tape" sounds pretty expressive.

Comment: "Chewing gum and bailing wire" was the term when I was younger.